# What setup would you recommend for a serverside Synthesizer?

Tags: audio, web, synthesizer

briefly put, I want to create a Website, that outputs an audiostream based on input given by the client in a Synthesizer-like interterface.
Just so everyone accessing this site will have the exact same audiostream and state of interface, I want all the work to be done by the server and only let the client manage input.
While I am not a newbie to Programming, I am a bit overwhelmed by the amount of possibilities to implement that. Can you recommend a practical setup for this, like which libraries (programming language may be tied to this) to use serverside, clientside and which technology is the most efficient way for communicating between them?
I know, this isnt the quickest question to answer, but I would really appreciate your help.

PS: This project is meant to be mostly educational to me and not of any commercial use or anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Synthesizer" is very vague... it isn't clear what functionality you are expecting and at what latencies.

In any case, I would probably start with Node.js and an implementation of the Web Audio API.  https://github.com/sebpiq/node-web-audio-api  Unfortunately, that package isn't exactly finished, but it's the most along that I know of.

Liquidsoap also has quite a bit of functionality that you might find useful.

Depending on your needs, a different approach would be to have your server application use OSC or MIDI control professional soft synths (or even real hardware!) and then stream the audio.

Comment: Thanks! This seems perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Further to @Brad's answer, sitting behind the web-server, you'd probably have a VST host with commercial soft-synth plug-ins (implementing these is high-effort - although it's anyone's guess whether the licensing extends to this application).

[Juce](http://www.juce.com) is probably where you'd go for the SoftSynth host.

The input would almost certainly be MIDI, but you'd probably need to use SYSEX or some side-channel for places where MIDI doesn't already provide you control messages.

The round-trip latency is likely to be too large for real-time playback  (although it's the worst-case latency that will be the real issue).

Audio-rendering not in real-time is a possibility though.

Comment: Okay, this makes it look a lot harder than @Brad's answer....Why does input need to be MIDI? It defenitely doesnt need to be any precise or functional to be used to create anything serious. The only importance is to have controls that influence the audiostream somehow. And a latency of some seconds should neither be a problem.

Comment: MIDI: Because that is the input to VST soft-synths.